# Number of JVM instances on a Java EE server

Tags: jakarta-ee, jvm, containers, server

Java EE application servers like JBoss has both EJB container as well as servlet/web container (assuming my application has both servlets as well as EJBs).

Whenever we talk about application server we always use containers to logically identify the component. I have this doubt-

Is there any corresponds with JVM instances as well ? 
EJB container and Servlet container share same JVM instance or they have their own ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, EJB and Servlet containers share the same JVM instance, but works in different threads.

Comment: Of more interest is that each deployment unit executes in it's own class loader

Comment: In common case answer will be "yes". But in real world many variants  exists. For example, weblogic use several classloaders under deployment of one unit [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG288) You can (or can not) config preferences of classes loading procedure. But if you has complicated application, class loading will be headache for you.